# iptables forward specific port to specific nic

Tags: iptables

what I have in my ubuntu is:

```
eth0(local) = 192.168.1.1/24 attemp to be gateway for local network
eth1(net1) = 192.168.2.2/24 gateway is 192.168.2.1 is a DSL 1
eth2(net2) = 192.168.3.2/24 gateway is 192.168.3.1 is a DSL 2
```

what I want is:

```
port 22,53,80,443 force to use only through eth1
port 6881 to 6889 and other ports force to use only through eth2
```

How to make rules in iptables?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark packages which should go via `eth1`:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -t mangle -p tcp --dports 22,53,80,443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Add rule `eth1.out` to route marked packages:

```
echo "201 eth1.out" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip rule add fwmark 1 table eth1.out
```

Route all marked packages via `eth1`:

```
/sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1 table eth1.out
```

Route everything else via `eth2`:

```
/sbin/ip route add default via 192.168.3.1 dev eth2
```

If `MARK` rule won't work, try using `CONNMARK`.

Comment: is not working here is my ip route command  <br /> 192.168.3.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.2 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.2 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
default via 192.168.3.1 dev eth2 
default via 192.168.3.1 dev eth2  metric 100 
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1  metric 100

Comment: Try removing 192.168.0.2/24 route and one of 192.168.0.3/24 (there's two of them, with default metric and metric 100)

Comment: how about /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward set to 0 or 1

Comment: Yes, it surely has to be set to 1 since you're running a gateway

Comment: second rule is working, all is going out via eth2 is work fine buy marked rule is not working.(i deleted all gateway with metric 100)

Comment: Perhaps this post can help: http://www.sparksupport.com/blog/tag/port-based-routing

Comment: Thank you, it work on Debian 6.0 after I enable //iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE// and //iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE// but not on Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Please post your complete iptables rules (iptables -L) and routing table (ip rule show) on both debian and ubuntu.

Comment: sorry I already reinstall Debian on Ubuntu machine. I guest gateway with metric 100 on Ubuntu may cause problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I needed to port forward to another ip address on my raspberry pi 3 model b and this is how I accomplished it.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and uncommment the line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

reload sysctl or reboot your raspberry pi

```
sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

then run the following iptables commands

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1-p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.198:22
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1-p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.198:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1-p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.198:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1-p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.198:443

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```